# Delay between recording and playing a sound (android)

Tags: android, audio-streaming, audiorecord, audiotrack

I wrote an android application which play environment's sounds simultaneously.

```
int bufferSize;  
short audioData[] = new short[bufferSize];  

AudioRecord recorder = new ......;  
AudioTrack track = new .......;  

track.play();  

while(true){  
  recorder.read(audioData, 0, bufferSize);  
  track.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizze);  
}
```

This code work but sound playing non-continuously. I think exist a delay between record.read() and track.write().

Please help me to make sound playing continuously with no bad noise or crashes.
thanks...